# Merge 1d and 2d array to create a new 1d array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have 2 arrays as such:

```js
let x = ['1min', '2min', '3min', '4min']
let y = [
  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
  ['e', 'f', 'g'],
  ['h', 'i', 'j'],
  ['k', 'l', 'm']
]

let z = x.map(function(e, i) {
  return [e, y[i]];
});

console.log(z)
```

the output i'm trying to get is this:
`z = [[a,'1min'], [b,'1min'], [c,'1min'], [e,'2min'], [f,'2min'], [g,'2min'], [h,'3min'], [i,'3min'], [j,'3min'],  ...]`

Comment: Please add the code you've tried

Comment: ```var z = x.map(function(e, i) {
  return [e, y[i]];
});```

Comment: @DeepGunner should be `var z = y.map(function(e, i) { return [e, x[i]]; });`

Comment: @CodeManiac that's not exactly what OP wants

Comment: using my code the output comes as ```[[a,b,c,d], '1min'],[[e,f,g],'2min'],... ```

Comment: `var z = y.map((v,i)=> v.map(u=> [u, x[i]]))`

Comment: What are `a`,`b`, etc? Variable names or string literals?

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: @adiga duly noted. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var x = ['1min', '2min', '3min', '4min'] 
var y = [['a','b','c','d'],['e','f','g'],['h','i','j'],['k','l','m']]

var z = x.flatMap((e, i)=> y[i].map(f => [f, e] ));
console.log(z)
```